# Is it a "coincidence" that a monoid can be viewed as a category, or is there a more general phenomenon that this is a part of?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Monoids (and by extension, groups) can be viewed as one object categories. To my eye, this looks a bit like a "coincidence"; we are able to do this because the properties of function composition (which are then generalized by arrows in an arbitrary category) happen to make the homset $Hom(X,X)$ into a monoid for an set $X$. But is there something I'm missing? Is this part of a more general correspondence, which also allows us to view e.g. other algebraic objects, like rings, as categories of some type? Or is it just a one off for monoids?

Comment: Posting this as a comment because someone much more qualified than me will surely provide a better and more general answer. Similarly as monoids, rings can be viewed as a preadditive category with only one object since in a preadditive category End( $ X$) has a natural ring structure with sum given by the abelian group structure on Hom($X$,$X$) and composition of function as multiplication

Comment: I know modules can be viewed in a similar way (which I don't know how can be made precise) but I honestly have no idea how far this can go

Comment: Expecting to be corrected on this, but it seems unlikely that there is a general recipe for viewing algebraic objects as one-object categories. Consider for example semigroups. To see those as one-object categories, one would presumably have to weaken the notion of a category by dropping the requirement that identity morphisms exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it's not exactly clear what it means to be a "coincidence" here. The fact that monoids are the same as categories with one object is part of a general mathematical phenomenon of taking some definition $X$ and specialising some aspects of it to obtain a new definition $X'$. Sometimes this new definition $X'$ was already known under another name $Y$, but it doesn't seem reasonable to call the fact that "an X' is simply a Y" a coincidence: it's simply a mathematical fact.

However, in the case of monoids and categories, there is a principled way of specialising a family of definitions $X$ to obtain a new family of definitions $X'$ that does recover known definitions $Y$ in many examples.

> **Proposition.** Let $\mathcal V$ be a monoidal category. A [monoid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoid+in+a+monoidal+category) in $\mathcal V$ is the same as a [$\mathcal V$-enriched category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) with one object.

When $\mathcal V = \mathrm{Set}$ is the category of sets and functions, this says that monoids in $\mathrm{Set}$ (i.e. monoids in the ordinary, set-theoretic sense) are one-object categories, which recovers the classical observation. When $\mathcal V = \mathrm{Ab}$ is the category of Abelian groups, this says that monoids in $\mathrm{Ab}$ – which are precisely rings in the ordinary, set-theoretic sense – are one-object $\mathrm{Ab}$-enriched categories, which are also called [ringoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Ab-enriched+category) in analogy with the connection between groups and groupoids. When $\mathcal V = \mathrm{Vect}_k$ is the category of vector spaces over a field $K$, this says that monoids in $\mathrm{Vect}_K$ – which are precisely [algebras over the field](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/associative+unital+algebra) $K$ – are one-object $\mathrm{Vect}_K$-enriched categories, which are also called [algebroids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebroid).

Hence, in general, if you have some algebraic structure which can be viewed as a monoid in a suitable monoidal category $\mathcal V$, then there is a more general structure – namely $\mathcal V$-enriched categories – that may viewed analogously as the generalisation of monoids to categories. In this way, enrichment may be seen as a form of [horizontal categorification](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification).

It is possible to tell a similar story even for objects that are not monoids: for instance, one can consider semigroups in semigroupal categories $\mathcal V$, which are one-object $\mathcal V$-enriched [semicategories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory). However, the phenomenon generally becomes less interesting the less structure your objects have.